# Error in my first Magento SOAP program

Tags: api, soap

I wrote a program. It is my first program to access to the API when I am done and compiled it, it says the following error in

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'SOAPTesting.ServiceReference2.salesOrderListEntity[]' to
>   'SOAPTesting.ServiceReference2.salesOrderEntity[]'    G:\VISUAL STUDIO
>   2013 PROJECT
>   WORKSPACE\HarshiniPROJECT\SOAPTesting\SOAPTesting\Program.cs  29  38  SOAPTesting

So how to fix this error here is my program,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient mservice = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();
        string mlogin = mservice.login("dileepa", "takastakas");

        Debug.WriteLine(mlogin);
        filters mf = new filters();
        complexFilter[] cpf = new complexFilter[1];
        complexFilter mcpf = new complexFilter();
        mcpf.key = "increment_id";
        associativeEntity mas = new associativeEntity();
        mas.key = "gt";
        mas.value = "1008001";
        mcpf.value = mas;
        cpf[0] = mcpf;
        mf.complex_filter = cpf;
        salesOrderEntity[] soe = mservice.salesOrderList(mlogin, mf);
        if (soe.Length > 0)
        {

            foreach (salesOrderEntity msoe in soe)
            {
                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("" + msoe.billing_firstname + " " + msoe.subtotal);
                }
                catch (Exception merror)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("" + msoe.order_id + "" + merror.ToString());
                }
            }
        }



        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not with Magento, but it's with your code.
`salesOrderList` returns an array of objects with type `salesOrderListEntity` but you declared it as an array of `salesOrderEntity`.

Change this line

```
salesOrderEntity[] soe = mservice.salesOrderList(mlogin, mf);
```

to this:

```
salesOrderListEntity[] soe = mservice.salesOrderList(mlogin, mf);
```

You may also need to change

```
foreach (salesOrderEntity msoe in soe)
```

to

```
foreach (salesOrderListEntity msoe in soe)
```